# Drupal 8 - how to create a user account programmatically and validating the email address later

Tags: php, drupal-8, access-denied

I developed a custom module to create users using the business rules module. This works well.

```
$lang = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
        $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::create();

        // The Basics
        $user->setUsername(str_replace('@','',$mail));  
        $user->setPassword(user_password());
        $user->setEmail($mail);
        $user->enforceIsNew();  
        $user->set("init", $mail);
        $user->set("langcode", $lang);
        $user->set("preferred_langcode", $lang);
        $user->set("preferred_admin_langcode", $lang);
        $result = $user->save();
```

After this I am sending an email to the user with the "user rest link" `_user_mail_notify('register_no_approval_required', $user);`

When the user clicks on the link he get "access denied" error.

What do I have to change in the user creation code?

Comment: How the link has been created? Have you defined router for that?

Comment: Router? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable register_no_approval_required setting from admin configuration. and you have to activate the user from code.

```
$user->activate();
```

For more details have a look on the [link](http://allabouttodd.com/story/how-programmatically-create-user-drupal-8)

Comment: I do have register_no_approval_required enabled, but when I use $user->activate(), this activates the user immediately, what I don't want because the user has to validate his email address before.

Comment: Then why you are sending mail of register_no_approval_required. and also user have to be activated for access user links. If user is disable then user urls will not work.

Comment: In the standard registration process, the user is also marked as "blocked" till the user validates his email address.

Comment: I mean, you do not need to send _no_approval_required mail to user. and check the email verification setting in drupal admin. [more details](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2015-03-04/how-to-programmatically-create-a-user)

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understand. This module is not for admin purpose, but for normal users, so the email address has to be validated.

Comment: Send this mail notification 
`_user_mail_notify('password_reset', $user);`

Comment: This doesn't change anything. Not a surprise as the link generate in this email is the same.There is something we have to specify during user creation, that lets Drupal know that an activation email has been send for this account.

Comment: try `$user->activate();`, may be user already active but still not able to login because password is not set by user. because a blocked user can not reset password till admin activate it. are you getting my point.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal works in a strange way: an "active" user account doesn't mean it has the email address validated. The email validation is actually a way to log in and set a password. If the email address is not "valid" you cannot login, even though the account is "active", because you did not received the one time login link.

So if you programmatically create user accounts, you should activate them as well.

If the user is blocked and he clicks on the email link he doesn't become active. He get's an "access denied" error.